# Android softkeyboard size

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I am developing a softkeyboard for android with custom layout. It means i don't use the KeyboardView, i just create a new input method service and in the onCreateInputView i inflate my custom layout then implement onTouchListener for child views.
I want my custom softkeyboard height take 70% of the screen size. I try to set the layoutparams for my view but it is not affected.

```
public View onCreateInputView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    keyboardLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.full_keyboard, null);
            // Then here i set the height of the keyboard layout
            .....
}
```

My questions is whether the android system take control of the softkeyboard size. If yes, is there any work-around solution for that.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you expect to happen and what's currently happening? That one code line with 3 comments is useless.

Comment: Dear Shark, i want i softkeyboard height will take 70% of the screen! Now it just take a small part of screen height no matter what i try.

Comment: So it works as intended, just not big enough?

Comment: Not completely, i try to set the layout_height to match_parent but the keyboard heigh still got only a part of the screen height

Comment: There's a few flags you can set in AndroidManifest.xml regarding to softkey's behaviour but i don't think these will help. Still - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

But, you do realize that Android's layouting mechanisms do not let you use 70% of anything as a measurement in any of the layouts? :)

Comment: Dear Shark , thank you very much for your helping. I found out the problem, it because i didn't set the targetSDK and maxSDK in the android Manifest, so that the get screen size display.getSize() return wrong values.

Comment: Oh cool. Write it up as an answer and accept it, for future references.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your res->values\dimens.xml
and change your key_height;

eg- `<dimen name="key_height">70dip</dimen>`